# Как правильно верстать шаблон для WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Я в WordPress новичок и не совсем понимаю как правильно.

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно верстать с нуля и потом делать натяжку шаблона на WordPress или использовать уже готовую тему и ее редактировать? 
Или это зависит от ситуации?

Буду благодарна за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дочерние темы всё-таки больше для переопределения функциональности или отдельных стилей. Если делать с нуля, то можно взять шаблон-заготовку _s (Underscores). Это решит многие проблемы.

https://wpmag.ru/2014/underscores-wordpress-theme/

https://toster.ru/q/202561

Comment: Давно искала эту тему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала лучше научиться верстать с нуля и разбираться в этом очень хорошо. Далее просто брать то, что у уже сделано и "натягиваешь" его на WordPress. Это не трудно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

> Скажите, пожалуйста, нужно верстать с нуля и потом делать натяжку
>   шаблона на WordPress или использовать уже готовую тему и ее
>   редактировать? Или это зависит от ситуации?

Лучше всего использовать темы из [оф каталога](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/) с использованием [механизма дочерних тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B).
Особенно это важно для новичков.

И избегайте использовать темы "из интернета". Даже платные.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и с нуля создавать свою тему. Но проблем на сайте (для начинающего разработчика) будет немерено. Две недели назад создавал тему с нуля. Напоролся на следующие проблемы:

1. Надо самому подключать файл стилей style.css - иначе не работает, в отличие от дочерней темы.
2. Надо добавить поддержку RSS
3. Разрешить WP поддерживать теги title
4. Добавить поддержку картинок записей
5. Добавить размеры изображений
6. Зарегистрировать меню
7. Добавить поддержку html5
8. Добавить поддержку пользовательского логотипа
9. Добавить и зарегистрировать стартовый контент
10. Добавить поддержку стартового контента
11. Добавить favicon

Здесь я всего лишь перечислил все пункты, реализованные в моей основной теме внутри functions.php. И это, я абсолютно уверен, далеко не полный список для нормального современного сайта.

Ничего не понятно? Конечно. Придется немало почитать, чтобы понять, о чем вот это все.

Поэтому совет начинающему девелоперу: берите бесплатную тему, хоть стандартную WordPress типа twentyseventeen, хоть из репозитория, делайте от нее дочернюю тему и модифицируйте ее.

Вы получите сразу поддержу всего, о чем я написал выше (и о чем не написал). И ваш сайт будет современный, удобный для пользователя.