# Не работает меню сайта WordPress на локальном сервере

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, сервер

Есть сайт, в котором на локальном сервере меню не работает.

Сайт я сначала сверстала, потом перенесла на его на WordPress. Появляются точки, которых не должно быть. На хостинге все хорошо работает. Код и пути указаны те же и там и там. Много раз проверяла.  Я не понимаю в чем проблема и почему появляются точки, когда сайт находится на локальном сервере.

Возможно пути нужно указать по-другому. Пожалуйста, помогите решить вопрос.

Скриншот локального меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: WP жестко прописывает пути до файлов в Базе Данных, поэтому одинаковые пути "и там и там" неприемлемы. По одному скриншоту вообще невозможно понять что у Вас не так. Больше конкретики, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это часть кода CSS, которая отвечает за меню.#nav_wrapper{
  max-width:940px;
  background:#357f03;
  border-radius:8px 8px 0 0;
  height:75px;
  line-height:75px;
}

#nav{
  list-style:none;
  height:75px;
  float:left;
}

#nav li{
  float:left;
  padding:0px 15px 0px 30px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  }

#nav li a{
  display:block;
  font-family:droid-sans-bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size:16px;
  padding-right:30px;
}

#nav li a:hover{
  background: url(img/border.gif) no-repeat right top;
  color:#fef116;
  padding-right:30px;
}

Comment: Частина коду index.php,де є саме меню.<div id="header">
<div id="nav_wrapper">
    <!--<ul id="nav">
       <li><a href="">home</a></li>
       <li><a href="">About </a></li>
       <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="">blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="">contacts</a></li>
    </ul>-->
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => 'nav'));?>
 </div><!--end nav_wrapper-->
</div><!--end header-->

Comment: Это ссылка сайта на хостинге, на котором все работает..
http://mysite.natalia.pw/
 А точки появляются на локальном сервере

Comment: Существует ли файл на локаллке /wp-content/themes/v/style.css? Подключается ли еще один файл стилей?

Comment: Существует. Подключаю все файлы с помощью функции php, которые прописаны в файле functions.php.
<? Php function my_scripts_method () {
wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery-3.2.0.min ", get_template_directory_uri ().' /js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js ');
wp_enqueue_script ( 'script', get_template_directory_uri (). '/js/script.js');
wp_enqueue_style ( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri ());
}
add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts "," my_scripts_method');

register_nav_menu ( 'menu', 'Primary Menu');
?>
Здесь подключены стиле и js.

Comment: Причина в том, что Вы не те ответы послушали тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688549/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-wordpress

Comment: Не совсем понимаю. То лучше использовать готовую тему?

Comment: Все таки,подскажите пожалуйста, какая может быть причина в данной ситуации и как исправить меню?

Comment: дополните этим кодом вопрос, здесь это совсем не читаемо, невозможно разобраться в чем дело

Comment: какие стили показывает инспектор, на ul? и откуда они тянутся?

Comment: @Natalia Предоставьте максимум информации что бы люди могли предложить варианты решения. Вариация проблем просто колоссальна, тут практически невозможно угадать в чем может быть причина.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Вопрос решился. Я еще очень много не знаю по WordPress.

Comment: На будущее: оформляйте код в тексте вопроса, а не в комментариях! Именно на чтение кода тратится основное время программиста, а читать разодранный код в комментариях -- это издевательство. Ставлю вопросу минус. В целях профилактики. Чтобы в следующий раз оформляли правильно. Ничего личного.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте название меню на сервере и на локале в админке. И точки добавляются по дефолту, то есть нужно для `ul` убрать их с помощью `list-style-type: none;`

Comment: Я указала list-style: none. Но точки остались.

Comment: Cпасибо за помощь.